RSS/ATOM feeds for lorientlejour.com
I have been searching for RSS/ATOM feeds of L'Orient-Le Jour (prime French-language newspaper in the Middle East). I hope they have them, or that someone has made a bridge/scraper.
I will post an answer if I stumble upon them.

Ah. The bottom of the site attributes the CMS as "WhiteBeard". The documentation here seems to be a clue.

These "actions" apparently require API keys. Looks like no non-scraping way.
